# Remote login to SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server, iis, iis-7, firewall, windows

I am trying to remotely access MS SQL Server Express 2008.

- I have turned on service "SQL Server Browser"
- I have turned on service "SQL Server
  (SQLExpress)"
- I have enabled TCP/IP and set dynamic
  ports to blank and tcp port to 1433
  in properties
- I can connect localy(using ip) so my
  credentials are correct.
- I have a exceptions record in my
  windows firewall setting port 1433 as
  open.
- I have performed a system reboot
  making all services are still turned
  on.

After i try and connect via a remote computer I get this error.

> Cannot connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
>    ============================
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider)
>       -----------------------------------------------
>   Error Number: 3
>   Severity: 20
>   State: 0

Your ideas and solutions will be greatly appreciated.

KJ

**EDIT**
Hi and thanks for the quick responses. At present there is no connection string. I am trying to connect using: *SQL Server Management Studio 2008*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you switched on "Allow Remote Connections" under the Properties Page->Connections when you right click on the server in Management Studio.  Also, make sure that on both the server and client that you make TCP/IP the default protocol.

Comment: Yeap that option was turned on. I cannot see an option to make tcp the default protocol.

Comment: On your client, in SQL Server Configuration Manager, under the Native Client Configuration, there is an option for Client Protocols and a way to specify the order.

Comment: It was set 1. Shared memory. 2. Tcp/ip... I turned off shared memory and still have not been able to access it.

Comment: There was an external hardware firewall which i did not know about. argh. Thanks very much for your help.